# Generating an array of positions after XSLT processing

Tags: javascript, xslt

**Foreword**: I have a table that I'm creating in XSLT that has children (it is a tree view in table form).  I *was* handling the JS of hiding/showing child nodes manually but it's quickly becoming a mess and hard to maintain.  I've begun to play with  [JQTreeTable](http://www.hanpau.com/index.php?page=jqtreetable).

Here is an example input (this matches the JSFiddle link): http://pastebin.com/NQVHsy69

**Problem**: JQTreeTable needs to know how the nodes are related, via an array.  This is what it's supposed to look like: http://jsfiddle.net/vt7Xd/30/

If you look at the JavaScript:

```
var map1 = [0,      1,      1,      1,      1,      1,      6,      1      ];
            ^ 5600  ^ 5601  ^ 5602  ^ 5603  ^ 5604  ^ 5605  ^ 5606  ^ 5607
```

These are the position/relationship identifiers.  The first element is a root (0), and the next few are children of the first row.  Then the 7th row is a child of the 6th.

I need to generate this array in XSLT.  Using position() to get the proper level works fine, but how can I guarantee this array is generated at the end of processing, or would there be a way to append to the array during processing?  Is this even feasible?

Comment: What is your input? What is the exact output that you expect for that input?

Comment: Example input added (see pastebin link).  The JFiddle link is an exact example of what I want to see for the output.

Comment: And what is the expected output for that input? It appears to be a flat structure. I'm not seeing anything in there that relates to the array listed above.

Comment: Ah, I see your confusion.  It is indeed flat.  The array above is XSLT positions.  So ID 5600 is in position 1 (hence everything else is a child of 1).  Then 5605 is a child of 5604 which is in position six.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's the relationship between `ID` and `MasterID`.

Comment: I dis-ambiguated the array a bit.  I realized I'd forgotten a row in the example input so here's an updated version: http://pastebin.com/0Nds2jeN

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5928/discussion-between-parker-and-lwburk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by @lwburk is a good one, however it is quadratic in speed ( O(N^2) ).

**Here is a simple, linear speed ( O(N) ) solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kRowById" match="Row"
  use="ID"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vRows" select="/*/*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vTopIndex" select="1"/>

 <xsl:template match="Row" mode="pass1">
  <Row pos="{position()}">
   <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
  </Row>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/Row" mode="pass1"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vPass1" select=
  "ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  var map1 = [ <xsl:text/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vPass1"/>
  <xsl:text>];</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Row">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "key('kRowById', MasterID)/@pos
   -
    (MasterID = ID)
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (no XML document was provided inline in the question!!!):

```
<Rows>
    <Row>
        <ID>5600</ID>
        <MasterID>5600</MasterID>
        <Name>A Product</Name>
        <Owner>RyanB_Admin</Owner>
        <CompletionPercentage>1</CompletionPercentage>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ID>5601</ID>
        <MasterID>5600</MasterID>
        <Name>Requirements Gathering</Name>
        <Owner>RyanB_Admin</Owner>
        <CompletionPercentage>100</CompletionPercentage>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ID>5602</ID>
        <MasterID>5600</MasterID>
        <Name>Design</Name>
        <Owner>RyanB_Admin</Owner>
        <CompletionPercentage>0</CompletionPercentage>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ID>5603</ID>
        <MasterID>5600</MasterID>
        <Name>Development</Name>
        <Owner>RyanB_Admin</Owner>
        <CompletionPercentage>0</CompletionPercentage>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ID>5604</ID>
        <MasterID>5600</MasterID>
        <Name>Testing</Name>
        <Owner>RyanB_Admin</Owner>
        <CompletionPercentage>0</CompletionPercentage>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ID>5605</ID>
        <MasterID>5600</MasterID>
        <Name>Documentation</Name>
        <Owner>RyanB_Admin</Owner>
        <CompletionPercentage>0</CompletionPercentage>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ID>5606</ID>
        <MasterID>5605</MasterID>
        <Name>Special documentation</Name>
        <Owner>RyanB_Admin</Owner>
        <CompletionPercentage>0</CompletionPercentage>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ID>5607</ID>
        <MasterID>5600</MasterID>
        <Name>Implementation</Name>
        <Owner>RyanB_Admin</Owner>
        <CompletionPercentage>0</CompletionPercentage>
    </Row>
</Rows>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
  var map1 = [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1];
```

**Explanation**:

1. This is a two pass solution. In the first pass we copy all element "as-is" but adding a `pos` attribute to every `Row`. The value of this new attribute is the relative position of this `Row` among its siblings `Row` elements.
2. In the second pass for every `Row` we get its master `Row` (using a key for very fast ( O(1) ) access) and then we output the value of this master's `pos` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The following stylesheet relates each `Row` to the `Row` preceding it that has the same `MasterID`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>var map1 = [</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/Row"/>
        <xsl:text>];</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Row[ID=MasterID]">0</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Row">
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::Row[
            ID=current()/MasterID]/preceding-sibling::Row) + 1."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this input:

```
<Rows>
    <Row>
        <ID>5600</ID>
        <MasterID>5600</MasterID>
        <Name>A Product</Name>
        <Owner>RyanB_Admin</Owner>
        <CompletionPercentage>1</CompletionPercentage>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ID>5601</ID>
        <MasterID>5600</MasterID>
        <Name>Requirements Gathering</Name>
        <Owner>RyanB_Admin</Owner>
        <CompletionPercentage>100</CompletionPercentage>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ID>5602</ID>
        <MasterID>5600</MasterID>
        <Name>Design</Name>
        <Owner>RyanB_Admin</Owner>
        <CompletionPercentage>0</CompletionPercentage>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ID>5603</ID>
        <MasterID>5600</MasterID>
        <Name>Development</Name>
        <Owner>RyanB_Admin</Owner>
        <CompletionPercentage>0</CompletionPercentage>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ID>5604</ID>
        <MasterID>5600</MasterID>
        <Name>Testing</Name>
        <Owner>RyanB_Admin</Owner>
        <CompletionPercentage>0</CompletionPercentage>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ID>5605</ID>
        <MasterID>5600</MasterID>
        <Name>Documentation</Name>
        <Owner>RyanB_Admin</Owner>
        <CompletionPercentage>0</CompletionPercentage>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ID>5606</ID>
        <MasterID>5605</MasterID>
        <Name>Special documentation</Name>
        <Owner>RyanB_Admin</Owner>
        <CompletionPercentage>0</CompletionPercentage>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ID>5607</ID>
        <MasterID>5600</MasterID>
        <Name>Implementation</Name>
        <Owner>RyanB_Admin</Owner>
        <CompletionPercentage>0</CompletionPercentage>
    </Row>
</Rows>
```

Produces the following output:

```
var map1 = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1];
```

Note that this takes the most straightforward approach of looking up each `Row` element's master when it's processed, which might not perform well on very large documents.